Converting vector points to raster
I'm currently working through An Introduction to Species Distribution Modelling (SDM) Using QGIS and R by Colin MacLeod, and I am having issues with the first exercise, which requires me to convert Harbor Porpoise point data into a raster data layer.
The step-by-step instructions are based on an older version of QGIS 2.8.3 (Windows), which hasn't been an issue until step 4, where the instructions call for setting the Raster resolution in map units per pixel which does not exist in any of the rasterization tools in QGIS 3.41. I assume this was replaced by the Output Raster Size Units dropdown, but neither options ("pixel" or "georeferenced map units") are giving me the result I need.
The instructions also call for setting the extent of the raster through an editing field that should allow me to input specific extent coordinates (-te -130000 56000 50000 396000 -burn 1), but this too doesn't seem to exist in the current QGIS version of the rasterize tools. Instead, I see Output extent that I can set to Calculate from Layer, Current Map Canvas Extent, or Draw on Map Canvas, none of which have been successful. I have inputted the extent code directly into this field as well, to no success.
I've played around with the parameters in many different iterations, but none of them have produced the intended layer. I have tried entering the extent code into the Additional Command Line Parameters (optional) within the Advanced Parameters dropdown, and other modifications based on what I've seen others do. No luck with anything I've tried.
I've attached a photo of the instructions and the intended result. I can provide more details about the data specifically as well if needed, in case there is some issue with the data itself (directly downloaded from the workbook's website) that is preventing me from moving on in the exercise. For example, where the book calls the point data HARBOUR_PORPOISE_PROJECT, the data is now just Harbour_Porpoise. Not sure if I need to do any more data manipulation because of this.
The data can be found at: GISinEcology.com/GIS-for-biologists-workbooks/




What tool are you supposed to use to rasterize the points?

@Bera The book wants me to use the “Rasterize (Vector to Raster)” tool, but when it failed, I’ve also tried similar tools by GRASS, which were no help.

Try Rasterize (vector to raster)
My points are in coordinate system 3006 which has meters as units. So the pixel size is 500*500 m.
I dont specify an extent so the extent of the output is the minimum bounding rectangle of the point layer.


I did try this tool. It’s the tool the book wants me to use. Maybe it’s the CRS that is the problem, because the book had me use a custom CRS meant to best represent the North Sea area. If I just use a standard CRS, it might work better.
